# Java: Why Doesn't My While Statement Work With My Case 2?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a simple program that outputs the lyrics of a song when the specified number is inputted. The problem is that my second case will not output, but only outputs the first case. When I try to output the second case, it still outputs the first. Regardless if I make two while statement or not, this still happens. Can someone help me fix my code?

Here it is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lyrics {
public static void main (String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int one, two, uone, utwo;
        one = 1;
        two = 2;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Lyrics Finder!");
        System.out.println("Press the number beside the song to see the lyrics!");
        System.out.println("1) Thank For The Memories - Fall Out Boy");
        System.out.println("2) Take Me To Church - Hozier");
        uone = input.nextInt();
        utwo = input.nextInt();
        switch (one){
        case 1:
            //code goes here for option 1
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Thank For The Memories - Fall Out Boy Lyrics");
            System.out.println("         ==          ");
            System.out.println("I'm gonna make it bend and break");
            System.out.println("Say a prayer but let the good times roll");
            System.out.println("In case God doesn't show");
            System.out.println("(Let the good times roll, let the good times roll)");
            System.out.println("And I want these words to make things right");
            System.out.println("But it's the wrongs that make the words come to life");
            System.out.println("Who does he think he is?");
            System.out.println("Who does he think he is?");
            System.out.println("Better put your fingers back to the keys");
            //continue song here
            break;
        case 2:
            //retype all code her for it to reset
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Take Me To Church - Hozier");
            System.out.println("          ==             ");
            System.out.println("My lover's got humour, She's the giggle at a funeral");
            System.out.println("Knows everybody's disapproval, I should've worshipped her sooner");
            System.out.println("If the heavens ever did speak, She's the last true mouthpiece");
            System.out.println("Every Sunday's getting more bleak, A fresh poison each week");
            System.out.println("We were born sick you heard them say it");
            System.out.println("My church offers no absolutes, She tells me Worship in the bedroom");
            break;
  }
        while (uone == one){
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("<-=LYRICS ABOVE=->");
            System.out.println("<-=OPTIONS=->");
            System.out.println("Press the number beside the song to see the lyrics!");
            System.out.println("1) Thank For The Memories - Fall Out Boy");
            System.out.println("2) Take Me To Church - Hozier");

            uone = input.nextInt();
            utwo = input.nextInt();
            switch (one){
            case 1:
                //code goes here for option 1
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Thank For The Memories - Fall Out Boy Lyrics");
                System.out.println("         ==          ");
                System.out.println("I'm gonna make it bend and break");
                System.out.println("Say a prayer but let the good times roll");
                System.out.println("In case God doesn't show");
                System.out.println("(Let the good times roll, let the good times roll)");
                System.out.println("And I want these words to make things right");
                System.out.println("But it's the wrongs that make the words come to life");
                System.out.println("Who does he think he is?");
                System.out.println("Who does he think he is?");
                System.out.println("Better put your fingers back to the keys");
                //continue song here
                break;
            case 2:
                //retype all code her for it to reset
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Take Me To Church - Hozier");
                System.out.println("          ==             ");
                System.out.println("My lover's got humour, She's the giggle at a funeral");
                System.out.println("Knows everybody's disapproval, I should've worshipped her sooner");
                System.out.println("If the heavens ever did speak, She's the last true mouthpiece");
                System.out.println("Every Sunday's getting more bleak, A fresh poison each week");
                System.out.println("We were born sick you heard them say it");
                System.out.println("My church offers no absolutes, She tells me Worship in the bedroom");
                break;
        }
 }
}
}
```

When the user types the number one, this should be outputted:

```
System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Thank For The Memories - Fall Out Boy Lyrics");
                System.out.println("         ==          ");
                System.out.println("I'm gonna make it bend and break");
                System.out.println("Say a prayer but let the good times roll");
                System.out.println("In case God doesn't show");
                System.out.println("(Let the good times roll, let the good times roll)");
                System.out.println("And I want these words to make things right");
                System.out.println("But it's the wrongs that make the words come to life");
                System.out.println("Who does he think he is?");
                System.out.println("Who does he think he is?");
                System.out.println("Better put your fingers back to the keys");
                //continue song here
                break;
while (uone == one){
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("<-=LYRICS ABOVE=->");
                System.out.println("<-=OPTIONS=->");
                System.out.println("Press the number beside the song to see the lyrics!");
                System.out.println("1) Thank For The Memories - Fall Out Boy");
                System.out.println("2) Take Me To Church - Hozier");
```

When the user types the number 2, this should be outputted:

```
System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Take Me To Church - Hozier");
                System.out.println("          ==             ");
                System.out.println("My lover's got humour, She's the giggle at a funeral");
                System.out.println("Knows everybody's disapproval, I should've worshipped her sooner");
                System.out.println("If the heavens ever did speak, She's the last true mouthpiece");
                System.out.println("Every Sunday's getting more bleak, A fresh poison each week");
                System.out.println("We were born sick you heard them say it");
                System.out.println("My church offers no absolutes, She tells me Worship in the bedroom");
                break;
while (uone == one){
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("<-=LYRICS ABOVE=->");
                System.out.println("<-=OPTIONS=->");
                System.out.println("Press the number beside the song to see the lyrics!");
                System.out.println("1) Thank For The Memories - Fall Out Boy");
                System.out.println("2) Take Me To Church - Hozier");
```

**Please note that I am very new to coding, so please try to explain the best that you can. If not, I still may be able to understand, but regardless, please briefly explain your solution.**

Comment: because you only asign a value to the "one" int and it's 1

Comment: I don't really follow your code at all, but you may want to write `switch(uone)` instead of `switch(one)`, because `uone` is the variable that contains the user's input at the point that you're checking.

Comment: Because the thing you're switch-ing on is always 1?

Comment: I think it's fair to say that we all have been there...

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show what is being outputted?

Comment: I'm very sorry everyone, i am very new to this ;) I will edit my question accordingly @dwjohnston.

Comment: Also, is your title wrong? Do you mean to ask 'Why _DOESN'T_...'?

Comment: @dwjohnston It's no use, instead of checking the case against the "uone" int he's checking it against "one" and never change its value

Comment: Yes @dwjohnston, it has been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
    uone = input.nextInt();
    utwo = input.nextInt();
    switch (one){
```

To

```
    int choice = input.nextInt();

    switch (choice)
```

Comment: This works, however, it seems that the while statement doesn't loop. Also, if I were to chose option 1 first, then option 2, option 1 would still show up.

Comment: Your loop must be based on the value of choice but I did not see a value in your list that was relevant. I would suggest adding a 0 stop to your list and then your while would be `while ( choice != 0)`

Comment: Also please put your choice in a method that can be called twice instead of replicating code. This not only makes it easier for you but for anyone that is trying to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: With your help, and also messing around a little, we managed to fix the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I missed the second part of your comment.  You need to change the`int choice = input.nextInt();` inside the loop to `choice = input.nextInt();`